# Why does building a release APK fail only when android:debuggable="false" is set?

Tags: android, scala, ant, proguard

Recently, the Google Play Store seems to be enforcing that all uploaded apps must set `android:debuggable="false"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I previously had `android:debuggable="true"` set.

However, when I set `android:debuggable="false"` my `ant clean release` blows up in the `-obfuscate:` step.

ProGuard seems to be the culprit:

`/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r21.1/tools/ant/build.xml:875: Can't write [/Users/-/Code/android/bin/proguard/obfuscated.jar] (Can't read [/Users/-/Code/android/libs/android-async-http-1.4.3-no-redirect.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [com/a/a/a/b.class == android-async-http-1.4.3-no-redirect.jar:com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient$1.class]))`

Any guidance on how to proceed? What changes in the obsfuscate step when doing a release build with `android:debuggable="true"` vs a release build with `android:debuggable="false"`?

Some additional details:

- doing a standard `ant clean release`
- project is actually written in Scala
- using the level 17 build tools
- ProGuard 4.4

Comment: Are you sure that it's an issue caused by setting android:debuggable? Note that the default value is false, so you can just remove it and try to build again.

Comment: Here's the strange thing -- I definitely am. It the release build works when `android:debuggable="true"` and it fails when I remove that property or set it to `android:debuggable="false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was including a few third-party libraries in my `proguard-project.txt` like so:

`-injar "libs/android-async-http-1.4.3-no-redirect.jar"`

I removed all of the `-injar` libraries and replaced the proguard `post-compile` step in my ant `build.xml` with a `debug-obfuscation-check` task:

```
<target name="-debug-obfuscation-check">
 <property name="proguard.enabled" value="true" />
 <path id="out.dex.jar.input.ref" />
</target>
```

Still not sure what happened. Apparently using `-injars` for libraries in proguard is a really bad practice (according to the ProGuard manual). I blame everything else on the hassle of using scala for android projects.